# Fastest way to check whether $ax+by+cz=d$ has positive integer solutions, exact solutions are not required

Tags: diophantine-equations

What is the fastest way to check whether $ax+by+cz=d$ has positive integer solutions, exact solutions are not required.

We know if $\gcd(a,b,c)$ is not a factor of $d$, it does not have solutions, but if it is factor it can not guarantee of existence of solution.

Comment: "but if it is factor it can not guarantee of existence of solution."  Why not?  Have you tried to prove that or find a counter example.

Comment: Because she wants the solutions to be positive.

Comment: See the [Frobenius Coin Problem.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coin_problem)

Comment: For any fixed number of coin denominations, there is an algorithm computing the Frobenius number in polynomial time: http://web.iitd.ac.in/~atripath/publications/FP_3-var.pdf          But it is perhaps not able to answer my question..